cytoscape.js Set neighbour nodes/relations visible with click on node
I'd like a script that shows related nodes and their connecting relations with an interaction (e.g., clicking on a node). I'm pretty new to Cytoscape's functionality and would love some hints to solve that task. Below is a more formal formulation:
Starting point:
(A:{visible})-[a:{invisible}]->(B:{invisible})-[b:{invisible}]>(C:{invisible})
After interaction:
(A:{visible})-[a:{visible}]->(B:{visible})-[b:{invisible}]->(C:{invisible})
So I'm sure there is a way to do this. You may have a look at my actual code on GitHub.
The idea is to hide all nodes despite one as a starting point and be able to investigate further relations over time.
Thank you for your help!

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Just got a solution for those who have a similar desire.
adapted from the solution here, thanks Stephan!
left click set neighbors visible, right-click set node invisible.


var cy = window.cy = cytoscape({
    container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  
    boxSelectionEnabled: false,
    autounselectify: true,
  
    style: [{
        selector: 'node',
        css: {
          'content': 'data(id)',
          'text-valign': 'center',
          'text-halign': 'center',
          'height': '60px',
          'width': '60px',
          'border-color': 'black',
          'border-opacity': '1',
          'border-width': '10px',
          'shape': 'data(shape)'
        }
      },
      {
        selector: '$node > node',
        css: {
          'padding-top': '10px',
          'padding-left': '10px',
          'padding-bottom': '10px',
          'padding-right': '10px',
          'text-valign': 'top',
          'text-halign': 'center',
          'background-color': '#bbb'
        }
      },
      {
        selector: 'edge',
        css: {
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle'
        }
      },
      {
        selector: ':selected',
        css: {
          'background-color': 'black',
          'line-color': 'black',
          'target-arrow-color': 'black',
          'source-arrow-color': 'black'
        }
      },
      {
        selector: '.hidden',
        css: {
          'display': 'none'
        }
      }
    ],
  
    elements: {
      nodes: [{
          data: {
            id: 'n0',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n1',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
        
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n2',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
       
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n3',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
   
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n4',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
       
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n5',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
     
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n6',
            shape: 'rectangle'
          },
   
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n7',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
     
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n8',
            shape: 'rectangle'
          },
     
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n9',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
   
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n10',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
    
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n11',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
      
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n12',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n13',
            shape: 'rectangle'
          },
 
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n14',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
     
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n15',
            shape: 'rectangle'
          },
   
        },
        {
          data: {
            id: 'n16',
            shape: 'ellipse'
          },
      
        }
      ],
      edges: [{
          data: {
            source: 'n0',
            target: 'n1'
          },
  
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n1',
            target: 'n2'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n1',
            target: 'n3'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n2',
            target: 'n7'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n2',
            target: 'n11'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n2',
            target: 'n16'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n3',
            target: 'n4'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n3',
            target: 'n16'
          },
 
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n4',
            target: 'n5'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n4',
            target: 'n6'
          },


        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n6',
            target: 'n8'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n8',
            target: 'n9'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n8',
            target: 'n10'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n11',
            target: 'n12'
          },
 
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n12',
            target: 'n13'
          },
 
        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n13',
            target: 'n14'
          },

        },
        {
          data: {
            source: 'n13',
            target: 'n15'
          },

        },
      ]
    },
  
    layout: {
      name: 'dagre',
      padding: 5
    }
  });
  
  cy.nodes('[id != "n0"]').classes('hidden');
  cy.nodes().on('click', function () {
    this.outgoers().each(function(ele) { 
        if (ele.hidden()) {
            
        }
        ele.classes("");

        })
        ;
    })
    cy.nodes().on('cxttap', function () {
        this.classes('hidden')});
body {
    font: 14px helvetica neue, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  }
  
  #cy {
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    float: left;
  }
<html>

<head>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimal-ui">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.2.17/cytoscape.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/dagre@0.7.4/dist/dagre.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre/1.5.0/cytoscape-dagre.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="cy"></div>
  <script src="code.js"></script>
</body>

</html>



